# Does changing the Vertical Coordinate System of a LAS file changes the actual height/elevation values?

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, vertical-transformation

I would like to know should/does the original height values get updated if I change the vertical coordinate system.

I already have the las dataset in **WGS 1984**

[image]

Now, I used the Extract LAS Geoprocessing Tool, and in the environment settings assigned the below HCS and VCS:

[image]

The output las dataset is assigned with the CRS, but the min and max values stay the same.

[image]

So, do the actual values change, if yes what is going wrong in ArcGIS Pro or my workflow? I have tested the same in another platform https://spatix.com/ [spatix.com] and it does show a change in actual min and max values.

Comment: Maybe ArcGIS does not know the vertical CS of the source. WGS84 (EPSG:4326) is 2D.

Comment: I did though of this, and as a test tried transforming the Test las file with BNG+Newlyn to something else but it did return the same values? Do the raw las should have the VCS assigned to work in Pro, or should I test using the project tool first and then the Extract LAS?

Comment: Have you tried the Convert LAS tool https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/conversion/convert-las.htm?

Comment: Yes, I did try it, but I suspect the tool does not apply or can be used for defining the output CRS.

Comment: My primary goal is to know if the change in CRS should change the actual height values? So let's assume a scenario where the source LAS had the VCS, and in that case, should the change I made to its VCS must change the source z values?

Comment: I think it should change height values if question is not just about fixing wrong CRS metadata. Maybe these blog posts are useful https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-data-interoperability-blog/don-t-leave-las-behind/ba-p/883680 https://medium.com/on-location/reprojecting-point-clouds-to-nzvd2016-b8724bbe1635